# Can't restore Azure bacpac into localdb with SqlPackage

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have made a backup of my SQL Azure in a bacpac file and when I try to import the bacpac in localdb it always fail.

Here is the command I use:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin> .\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Import 
/SourceFile:"C:\Users\S\Desktop\MyDb.bacpac" 
/TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDb; Integrated Security=true;"
```

And here is the error message:

```
*** Error importing database:Data cannot be imported into target because it 
contains one or more user objects. Import should be performed against a new, empty 
database.
Error SQL0: Data cannot be imported into target because it contains one or more
user objects. Import should be performed against a new, empty database.
```

My machine is newly installed, and I have never used localdb at all.

Comment: have you tried different localdb names?

Comment: Actually, I made it working, I try to repodruce my mistake and will update information here. It was not coming from the name. It seems that VS2013 added the mdf file to the wrong place when I created the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the problem on another machine today and solved it like that:

Before doing this make sure to backup all other database

Delete this directory

```
C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0
```

Then open a command prompt

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
```

And after that everything went fine...

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem and, after some frustration, solved it.

What had happened is that you have created, most likely by mistake, a user object in the model Database.  On Management Studio look under Databases\System Databases\model.   This is the template that is used when you create a new database, and is used when importing the bacpac.  If there are objects (such as a table) in the model, they are automatically created at the same time as the new database.  The bacpac import then encounters them in what it expects to be a blank database, and so immediately fails.

You'll also see these same objects created if you manually create a new database.

Deleting the object(s) from the model database solves the problem.

Comment: This is the right answer! Kudos to you on discovering that this was the issue. You deserve way more upvotes.

Comment: And upvotes you shall have, even after 6 years ;-)