# SQL Server - can't import data-tier application from bacpac file (trying to move db + data from Server 2016 to 2014 SP1)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-tier-application

I'm trying to get a workable method to transfer a database schema and data from a SQL Server 2016 install to a SQL Server 2014 install on a different network. It looks like Import/Export Data-Tier Application would be a perfect solution, and I've eliminated the other candidates.

However, when I try to test on the 2016 install by exporting and then importing, I get the following error on the Importing Database, Creating Deployment Plan and Initializing Deployment stages:

> Error SQL0: Data cannot be imported into target because it contains one or more user objects. Import should be performed against a new, empty database.

I've made sure that the destination Database is one that doesn't already exist (in fact the wizard won't let me try if it doesn't). I've tried exporting a copy of the database and deleting that copy before trying to import. I looked for answers and found [an answer for a different version with different files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52327/cant-restore-azure-bacpac-into-localdb-with-sqlpackage?newreg=172b6fc1351d41d09f9675645824b1d3). I didn't see anything for the problem on this version, and I don't know enough to try blindly adapting that answer.

The Extract/Deploy workflow with just dacpacs works fine, but I need to get the data as well.

Comment: Your question focuses in data tier application issues, yet your first sentence implies you are open to alternative methods. Are you  open to alternatives? Or do you want to focus only on this 1 approach?